# CSS - Using Hover on elements inside a tag?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to use hover for a couple divs inside a tag.

For example here

```
<a href="#">
<div class="nextmatch_wrap">
   <div class="clan12w">
      <div class="TeamLogos">
         <div class="Team" id="TeamContainer">
            <img src="#">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clan12w">
      <div class="TeamLogos">
         <div class="Team" id="TeamContainer">
            <img src="#">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you hover on the a tag I want a colored border to appear on the "TeamContainer" and "TeamLogos"

I'm not good with css but I have tried like this

```
a nextmatch_wrap, :hover #TeamContainer, a nextmatch_wrap, :hover .r-home-team{
border:solid 1px #25c2f5;
}
```

It works but somehow the hover is like always ON when your mouse is on anywhere in the page but when you move your mouse out of the browser page the hover goes away, Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not correct and the `<a>` tag is not closed. The `>` in the selector means that apply effect on `<a>` when it is hovered and `<a>` followed by `<div>`.

**Here is what you can do.**

```css
a:hover > div {
  border:solid 1px #25c2f5;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="nextmatch_wrap">
     <div class="clan12w">
        <div class="TeamLogos">
           <div class="Team" id="TeamContainer">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clan12w">
        <div class="TeamLogos">
           <div class="Team" id="TeamContainer">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the css you need to use exactly for what you want:

```
a:hover #TeamContainer, a:hover .TeamLogos{
    border:solid 1px #25c2f5;
}
```

The "," in a css's selector means that you're applying the same style to several elements and you use it to separate those elements *(i.e: in my case, I'm applying that border style to every `#TeamContainer` located inside an `<a>` tag that's being hover, AND to every `.TeamLogos` inside an `<a>` tag hovered.)*

You should add `:hover` immediately after the element that's being hovered, despite the element that's going to be affected.

The problem with your style's selector, is that you have `:hover` alone between commas, so that's selecting any element being hover.

Don't forget to close the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work :/ the hover doesn't work when i add it like this, i have closed the a tag its just i forgot to post it here : )

Comment: I'm sorry, TeamLogos is a class not an ID, you should use ".TeamLogos" instead of "#TeamLogos". My mistake! Does this work? a:hover #TeamContainer, a:hover .TeamLogos{
    border:solid 1px #25c2f5;
}

Comment: agh yes its a class not id xD no worries its my bad i didn't even look i just copy pasted

Comment: No actually i had to make it like this to work  .nextmatch_wrap:hover #TeamContainer {
border-color: rgb(255, 36, 35) !important;
}